# Can you create a PyCharm configuration in a batch file/script?

Tags: python, pycharm

When pulling down code from Git my team often has to re-create their entire environment, re-install dependencies, and also setup Python configurations again. I want to find a way to automate this and also so that we can pass an environment back and forth between each other.

I am getting all the dependencies into a reqs.txt file using this

```
pip freeze > reqs.txt
pip install -r reqs.txt
```

and I have already placed this into a batch file to handle that portion of it.

Comment: Note: not about PyCharm: in git you can (and probably you should) setup hocks: script that will be run before or after some actions. I think your task fall in this generalized use (and so you may look on such directions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automation you asked can be achieved by imitating the behavior of PyCharm. Below, you will find an indicative Python script that can help accomplish this task:

```py
import os

# Get project path from user input
project_path = input("Enter project path: ")

# Get project name from the last directory in the path
project_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(project_path))

# Create venv in project path using system default Python installation
os.system(f"python -m venv {project_path}\\venv")

# Activate the virtual environment and update pip
activate_script = f"{project_path}\\venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat"
os.system(f"call {activate_script} && python -m pip install --upgrade pip")

# Install the dependencies from reqs.txt
install_command = f"{activate_script} && pip install -r {project_path}\\reqs.txt"
os.system(f"call {install_command}")

# Create .idea directory in project path
os.mkdir(f"{project_path}\\.idea")

# Create the .iml file
iml_content = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/venv" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>"""
with open(f"{project_path}\\.idea\\{project_name}.iml", "w") as iml_file:
    iml_file.write(iml_content)

print("Project configuration completed successfully.")
```

You can modify it accordingly to meet your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an option to create an XML file of my configuration.

In PyCharm from the Run/Debug Configurations menu (dropdown options from next to play and debug buttons), click edit configurations. From there click the checkbox that says "Store as project file".

This will create an xml file that will be saved in the .idea folder and then can be opened, uploaded to git, etc.